# I was just going through an article about "Rediscover the Lost Art of Memory Optimization in Your Managed Code" by Erik Brown

Tags: c#

Can someone explain this !!
**Firstly** Demo  results in consuming 12 bytes, how did it consume 12, when it should be total 8 Bytes  (char = 2Bytes, int = 4 Bytes, char = 2Bytes)

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Demo d1 = new Demo();
            Demo2 d2 = new Demo2();
            var DemoSize = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(d1);
            var Demo2Size = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(d2);
        }
    }
    public struct Demo
    {        
        char c1;
        int i;
        char c2;
    }
    public struct Demo2
    {
        int i;
        char c1;
        char c2;
    }
}
```

**Secondly** Demo2 results in consuming 8 Bytes,how does the ordering of the types result in memory optimizing to 8 Bytes,What happens under the hood, can someone guide me to an article or link which spreads more light on this.

**lastly** How to figure out the memory a particular instance of a class consumes on the heap ?

Comment: http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/

Comment: Note that this only applies to structs with sequential layout, which are unmanaged structs (structs that only contain unmanaged types) or structs you've applied `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` to. If your struct contains a reference, or you've got a class, then the compiler will re-arrange the fields to reduce waste due to padding, and optimize efficiency.

Comment: Also https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cbrumme/2003/04/15/size-of-a-managed-object/

Comment: Thanks a lot steve & Canton7  :)  will go through the links